# how to exec command in new prompt using ant

Tags: selenium, ant

I am trying to run a command in ant to start the selenium server but it opens up in the same command prompt, is there anyway i can open it up in a new prompt?

```
<project>
<target name="startGRID">
    <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub"/>
    </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see a separate command prompt in which your server is run, use the dos `start` command, which does exactly that:

```
<exec dir="." executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="start"/>
  <arg value="java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub"/>
</exec>
```

The only issue I find with that is that, when the server is terminated, the new command prompt window will remain open. This can be worked around by wrapping the java command in a batch script, let's call it start-selenium.bat, with an `exit` statement at the end:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub
exit
```

then the Ant task becomes:

```
<exec dir="." executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="start"/>
  <arg value="start-selenium.bat"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: i tired that it said it was successful but didnt see another command prompt open up or anything

Comment: @hardik-patel ah ok, I see that I misunderstood your question, I edited my answer accordingly