# Start a new cmd.exe window in jenkins server with ANT

Tags: jenkins, ant, cmd

The ANT exec target open a bat file and execute in a new cmd.exe window.

The same is not working through Jenkins.

I want Jenkins to start a new cmd.exe window in jenkins server with ANT.

Comment: Can you show the build script that isn't working for you? By the way, do you need to run that only on windows platform? Possibly you looking for the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166912/how-to-exec-command-in-new-prompt-using-ant

Comment: Below code work fine while run through ANT and same is not working while integrating ANT to Jenkins build execution.'<target name="startjboss">      
    <!--<property name="batFileDir" location="${basedir}/resources" />-->

    <exec executable="cmd" dir="." spawn="false">
        <arg line="/C start D:\project\jboss-eap-6.1\bin\standalone.bat -b serverip"/>
    </exec>                
</target>'

Comment: Why does it explicitly needs to be run in a separate `cmd window`? For example, **jenkins** is running on a _remote machine_, and you accessing it thru browser in _your machine_, and invoke the build, where do you expect it to open the `command window`

Comment: I want Jenkins to start the bat file and exit the process. where our dev team will look in to the executed bat file on command window(Status of the application, application logs, etc)

Comment: jenkins should be able to run a batch file, that is not the question you put here. From the question - **start a new cmd.exe window**. Asking why it has to be done like that?

Comment: You state "it's not working" but no further information on what the error exactly is..... Could I ask an obvious question, is your Jenkins server running on windows? You are running a feature that is very platform specific.

Comment: I am running in windows server 2008. I have find a fix. Jenkins running as a service in windows platform cannot interact with system GUI. But if started from war can interact with the system. This works for me

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have got your answer already as you're posted this question long back. I am answering now to help others.

```
start cmd /K <command>
```

while jenkins running as a service, this command will never work like the way it works in command prompt. But if you run jenkins in a command prompt, it works as expected. But running jenkins in a command windows is not a good option.

I would suggest to configure a scheduled task that can run the batch script.
you can start the scheduled task from jenkins build using command `schtasks run`